# Software available only to root user?

Tags: rhel, root, path, privileges

I am trying to install HP Fortify on RHEL 6.4. I installed it as the root user and can see on the PATH but when I login with a different user I can't see the software in the path. I have updated the permissions to 777.

Is the solution to add the path to the etc/profile or is there a better recommended approach to install software for all users?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/219692/why-the-value-of-path-is-different-for-root-and-normal-user might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the solution to add the path to the etc/profile or is there a better recommended approach to install software for all users?

It depends on the software. Other approaches that might work include:

- If there is a `./configure` script, try getting it to install in a location that is already in everyone's path, such as `--prefix=/usr`.
- Try symlinking each application binary into a standard path location, such as `/usr/bin`.
- Try placing an adapter script in `/usr/bin` for each binary that prepends to `PATH` before running the corresponding application binary.